# some fields from node and to node output are equal to 0

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am generating a flow path using the flow direction grid and flow accumulation raster as input in stream to feature tool. I just want to know what it means to have 0 values in the from node and to node field and also the arcid values are 0.

Comment: Values in these fields is nothing but sequential node number starting with 0.

Comment: @FelixIP: could you pls elaborate sir..

Comment: Those fields belong to coverage features, which the tool may have been descended from, they have no relevance to shapefiles and feature classes because node features aren't supported in these models.

Comment: does it mean it is not included duringthe next processes?

Comment: I couldn't see them being important. If you do convert to a coverage and build for node then these fields will be auto generated; that said though, I wouldn't just delete them without making a backup - though I am fairly confident the tool will work just as well without those fields.

Comment: Nodes are not a part of output of this tool, which makes this info obsolete. This is unfortunate, because it would fascilitate all sort of hydrological analysis, e.g. tracing up/downstream.Most certainly they are created during the process.

Comment: @FelixIP I think your comment would be useful as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments:

by [Michael Stimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/15054/michael-stimson):

> Those fields belong to coverage features, which the tool may have been
>   descended from, they have no relevance to shapefiles and feature
>   classes because node features aren't supported in these models.
>
> I couldn't see them being important. If you do convert to a coverage
>   and build for node then these fields will be auto generated; that said
>   though, I wouldn't just delete them without making a backup - though I
>   am fairly confident the tool will work just as well without those
>   fields.

And by [@FelixIP](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/34531/felixip):

> Nodes are not a part of output of this tool, which makes this info
>   obsolete. This is unfortunate, because it would fascilitate all sort
>   of hydrological analysis, e.g. tracing up/downstream.Most certainly
>   they are created during the process.